# Android: open Activity from URL show instead of calling app in recent apps

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have an `IntentFilter` set in my Activity like:

```
<intent-filter>
            <data android:host="www.example.com" android:scheme="http" android:pathPrefix="/d/"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

its working great to launch the Activity when a link is pressed, the problem is that looking in recent apps, my Activity shows in the preview of the calling app, instead of having its own instance.

for example: if a link with the url is clicked from WhatsApp, in recent apps I see my Activity in the preview for WhatsApp, instead of seeing my app opened in addition to WhatsApp.

I checked other apps and none of them is acting like that.

how do I fix this ?

Comment: play with `"android:noHistory"`/`"android:launchMode"` (I really didn't get "example" part hehe)

Comment: what I meant is that with the standard launchMode my Activity opens in the caller app's task, which doesn't seem to be the expected behavior for an activity that handles web urls. seems like singleTask is doing the right thing, the problem is that if the Activity was already created, when clicking on the URL it isn't created again, just brought to the front. so how do I load dynamic content if onCreate isn't being invoked ?

Comment: ... override `onNewIntent`(or something like this) in `Activity`  ...